# c++ average function not working properly

Tags: c++, arrays, math

I am fairly new with c++, I am still learning; so please forgive me ahead of time :) I need some help with this c++ program. The program takes an array of grades and displays all the grades and outputs the average. Can someone check to see if there is a problem with my average algorithm? I am sure it is something simple. The results displayed aren't what I expect. see below..

expected

```
Student Grade 1 Grade 2 Grade 3 Grade 4 Ave Wt Ave
1   85  88  90  81  86.0    86.6
2   73  68  75  77  73.2    72.9
3   94  89  82  91  89.0    88.3
4   88  79  81  84  83.0    82.4
5   71  65  78  73  71.8    71.7
```

output

```
Student  Grade 1  Grade 2  Grade 3  Grade 4  Average  Wt Average
-------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  ----------
1        85        88        90        81        3.44788        86.6
2        73        68        75        77        3.16131        159.5
3        94        89        82        91        3.70485        247.8
4        88        79        81        84        3.45602        330.2
5        71        65        78        73        3.05328        401.9
```

Here is my code-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double avg = 0;
    double weightAve;

    //data type array name [rows] [columns]
    double grades[5][7] = {{1, 85.0, 88, 90, 81}, {2, 73, 68, 75, 77}, {3, 94, 89, 82, 91}, {4, 88, 79, 81, 84}, {5, 71, 65, 78, 73}};


    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < 7; column++)
        {
            //sum += grades[row][column];
            avg += grades[row][column];
            avg /=4; //divide avg by 4
            grades[row][5] = avg;
        }


            weightAve+=(0.2*grades[row][1]);
            weightAve+=(0.3*grades[row][2]);
            weightAve+=(0.3*grades[row][3]);
            weightAve+=(0.2*grades[row][4]);

            //store the wt avg
            grades[row][6]=weightAve;
    }





    //printing arrays
    cout << "Student  Grade 1  Grade 2  Grade 3  Grade 4  Average  Wt Average" << endl;
    cout << "-------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  ----------" << endl;
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row ++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < 7; column++)
        {

            cout <<grades[row][column] << "        ";

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you initialize each array[7] with just 5 values?

Comment: You don't need to write that much code for such a simple problem. Things like `std::array` or `std::vector` rather than C style arrays, range based for loops, `std::accumulate`, etc would probably help you. And if you ever want the median rather than the average, there's `std::sort` and `std::nth_element` which make that trivial as well.

Comment: Why did you put your student numbers into the grades array?

Comment: It seems like you forgot to reset `avg` to zero after each average.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dividing too often.
Move the division out of the loop:

```
    {
        //sum += grades[row][column];
        avg += grades[row][column];
        avg /=4; //divide avg by 4
        grades[row][5] = avg;
    }
```

->

```
    {
        //sum += grades[row][column];
        avg += grades[row][column];
    }
    avg /=4; //divide avg by 4
    grades[row][5] = avg;
```

Also, in order not to rely on uninitialised variables, only sum up the first 4 entries, which you initialised (credits JeJo):

```
for (int column = 0; column < 7; column++)
```

->

```
for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
```

As mentioned by Francois (credits), reset the variables, to cleanup after each line.
Move them into the outer loop and init them.

```
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        double avg = 0.0;
        double weightAve=0.0;
```

Comment: `avg` should also be reset after each average. Or `avg` can be made local to the outter loop.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Good point. Allow me to pick that up in my answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch: this `for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++)` should be `for (int column = 1; column < 4; column++)` as he has 4 col of marks for each students.

Comment: @JeJo Well spotted. Allow me to pick that up.

Comment: @Yunnosch thank you for your help and everyone else's help! I knew it was something simple :) I made those changes you recommended and a few other changes now that I got some clarity from you guys. thanks again for helping

Answer (score 5):

Basically this was the error with your code. First of all your column length is only 5 so running it till 7 is not a good idea. Second you are dividing inside the bracket that means as soon as the first value comes in, it gets divided.

eg 85/4  +(85/4+ 88)/4 ....

that's why you are getting a wrong answer.  Here is the fix,

```
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {   
        avg =0;
        weightAve =0;
        for (int column = 1; column <= 4; column++)
        {
            //sum += grades[row][column];
            cout << grades[row][column] << endl;
            avg += grades[row][column];


        }
            avg /=4;
            grades[row][5] = avg;

            weightAve+=(0.2*grades[row][1]);
            weightAve+=(0.3*grades[row][2]);
            weightAve+=(0.3*grades[row][3]);
            weightAve+=(0.2*grades[row][4]);

            //store the wt avg
            grades[row][6]=weightAve;
    }
```

Comment: Yunnosch, I added mine answer as soon as I saw the problem never saw your posted solution

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that it wasn't added in my solution